# list append skipping a row in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, cs50

i'm trying to solve a problem set in cs50 course
i read data from csv file via csv.DictReader and i want to take the first row - which contain the headers- in a list and then the other rows in another list
my implementation was like this

```
line_count = 0
with open(argv[1], "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        if line_count == 0:
            fields = row
            line_count += 1
        else:
            people.append(row)
            line_count += 1
''' or
fields = []
with open(argv[1], "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fields = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        people.append(row)
'''
```

in both manners, the first row in my csv file after the headers is skipped 
the csv looks like this

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
```

Alice is skipped and doesn't go into my list

Comment: `csv.Dictreader` already skips the header row for you, so you don't need to manually skip it.

Comment: thanks @Oli i used syntax like this and now it is working for me csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            fields = row
            break
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            people.append(row)

Answer (score 1):

`csv.DictReader` assumes there is a header, and pre-reads it for you. One of the qualities of a `DictReader` is that you can use the column names to access data in the rows, so it always reads the first line as headers. Your commented-out code is close to working, i.e.

```
FirstName,LastName,Age
John,Doe,25
Jane,Doey,26
```

can be read with:

```
with open(argv[1], "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fields = csvreader.fieldnames  # ['FirstName','LastName','Age']
    for row in csvreader:
        people.append(row)
```